# Adding MSRP to product page for WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm currently trying to add a new text-field to my product page. I want to display the MSRP price of my products next to the product. Like on the image below. The MSRP should be on where the red line is.

[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUwyO.png)

I've done quite a bit of research on the topic. There are a few plugins that would fix the problem. However most of them have either bad reviews or are paid. I've succesfully added a meta field for the MSRP. However when i add a price to this field it doesn't show up on the product page at all.

```
function bbloomer_display_RRP() {
global $product;
if ( $product->get_type() <> 'variable' && $rrp = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'rrp', true ) ) 
  {
    echo '<div class="woocommerce_rrp">';
    _e( 'RRP: ', 'woocommerce' );
    echo '<span>' . wc_price( $rrp ) . '</span>';
    echo '</div>';
  }
 }
```

The code above should display the MSRP price on the product page. However it doesn't

Regards,

Luuc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you adding `bbloomer_display_RRP` to any hook? The function by itself, won't do anything. Based on your screenshot, I would add it to the `woocommerce_template_single_price` hook with a priority of `5` so that it will appear just before the price does.

```
/**
 * Add RRP Field to product data metabox
 */
function kia_add_RRP_to_products() {          
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array( 
        'id' => 'rrp', 
        'class' => 'short wc_input_price', 
        'label' => __( 'RRP', 'woocommerce' ) . ' (' . get_woocommerce_currency_symbol() . ')',
        'data_type' => 'price', 
    ));      
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_pricing', 'kia_add_RRP_to_products' );   

/**
 * Process, verify and save product data
 *
 * @param  WC_Product  $product
 */
function kia_save_RRP( $product ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['rrp'] ) ) {
        $rrp = wc_format_decimal( wc_clean( wp_unslash( $_POST['rrp'] ) ) );
        $product->update_meta_data( 'rrp', $rrp );
    } else {
        $product->delete_meta_data( 'rrp' );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'kia_save_RRP' );

/**
 * Display RRP on front-end in product summary
 */
function kia_display_RRP() {
    global $product;

    $rrp = '10';

    if ( ! $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
        
        $rrp = $product->get_meta( 'rrp', true );

        if ( $rrp ) {
            echo '<div class="woocommerce_rrp">';
            printf( __( 'RRP: %s', 'your-textdomain' ), wc_price( $rrp ) );
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'kia_display_RRP', 5 );
```

Comment: I am using this code. The snippet above is the code that is supposed to show the price. Check out this link. https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-display-rrp-msrp-manufacturer-price/

Comment: You didn't answer my question though about whether you are actually calling `add_action()`? It's in the tutorial as `add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'bbloomer_display_RRP', 9 );` but it's not referenced in your question. So I'm trying to discern whether that's a copy/paste fail or if that's the reason nothing is displaying. Editing my snippet as the hook is wrong... copy/paste fail on my part.

Comment: I have the `add_action()` called on line 12. I noticed however that after the `bbloomer_display_RRP` there is a 9 which is missing in my code. Could that be the problem? This is what the code looks like on my end `add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_pricing', 'bbloomer_add_RRP_to_products' );` Please forgive me for being a little slow. Very newbie at wordpress and php. =)

Comment: No worries, we were all new once. That 9 number is the "priority". It determines the order of appearance/operation when multiple actions are added to the same hook. My code definitely displays a value when passed a test value (in lieu of meta) so perhaps you're having issues with saving the meta? I've updated their entire snippet to add some sanitization and use the Woo CRUD for saving meta. It's tested and working for me.

Comment: This seems to do the trick for me. One last question. By simply changing the priority number would that make it possible for me to place the value lower on the page? Thanks

Comment: A higher priority number (try 99) would make it come _after_ the other functions attached to `woocommerce_single_product_summary` but it would always stay on the `woocommerce_single_product_summary` hook. So other hooks that come later in the template would still be later. If the answer solves your question would you mind accepting the answer?

Comment: I see, thank you for taking the time to help me with my problem. I really do appreciate it. However I tried changing the priority to 99 and even 999 however it doesn't do anything. It should move it under the normal product price right? Or am I mistaken?

Comment: Where you are trying to move it? I suspect you need to move it to another hook to see a major difference.

Comment: I think I phrased the question wrong. I meant to move the text under the normal price.

Comment: In the [source](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/02cf0dfaed5923513de0c88add597d1560c2cfd2/includes/wc-template-hooks.php#L146) you can see that the priority for the price template is 10. So if you want your data to come after that, you need to use a later (higher) priority than 10... so 15 would be good as it would get you after the regular price, but before the excerpt which has a priority of 20.

Comment: But keep in mind this assumes you are still using the default Woo templates and your theme hasn't modified that at all.

Comment: I see, I will make some changes and see if it works, thanks alot!

Comment: I noticed that the source that you linked is located on the server of the website. Is this correct? If so I don't have acces to the sites server. Is there any way to edit the priority number outside of the server?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are asking? This code must be added either to your theme's functions.php file, a custom site-specific plugin, or if you don't have access to the site, via the [Code Snippets](https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/) plugin.

Comment: So the line of code that is highlighted in the source you link should be in a new snippet? I'm quite confused at the moment.

Comment: The source I linked is WooCommerce itself. It's for reference to show you what Woo is attaching to the `woocommerce_single_product_summary` hook. The code I pasted in the _answer_ is the snippet. That is the only thing that needs to be added either via your theme's functions.php or via the Code Snippets plugin. If you don't have server access, then then latter will be a better option for you.

Comment: Very well, I think I understand. You have been very helpful Helga. Thanks alot!